# How do I import/append assets from blender to upbge?

Tags: game-engine

Okay, so I've made some assets in blender 2.91.0 but, I want to put them into UPBGE to use them for a game I'm trying to make and I don't know how. Does anybody know how to help me get my 3d models/rigs,animations,etc into UPBGE from blender 2.91.0 ? I don't know how. I tried to just open the blend file in UPBGE but, that didn't work. I tried to use the append feature to get assets from a blend file I made in blender 2.91.0 but, that didn't work. I really don't know what to do. I'm new to using UPBGE.

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to BlenderStackExchange. I assume you downloaded and tried running a UPBGE 0.3x release? The latest version that is built on is Blender 3.0x, which may not be as compatibility to Blender 2.91.0 releases unfortunately. Unless you are attempting to import those Blender 2.91.0 models into say, a legacy UPBGE version such as UPBGE 0.25b, I'd suggest using the UPBGE 0.3x release built on Blender 2.91.0.

If my dates are correct, I believe this bild is built on Blender 2.91.0. If I am mistaken tell me and I'll track the correct one down or send you my local copy of UPBGE 0.3x built on 2.91.0.

## DOWNLOAD:

https://mega.nz/folder/k9MW1KiZ#UOKzjh3IQ0GEgjQ6GUc7ug/file/t5t3zYSY